# Pulling data asynchronously from third-party web service on Windows Azure Platform

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-worker-roles

I want to pull large amount of data, frequently from different third party API web services and store it in a staging area (this is what I want to decide right now) from where it will be then moved one by one as required into my application's database.

I wanted to know that can I use Azure platform to achieve the above? How good is it to use Azure platform for this task?

What if the data to be pulled is of large amount and the frequency of the pull is high i.e. may be half-hourly or hourly for 2,000 different users?

I assume that if at all this is possible, then the bandwidth, data storage and server capability etc. will not be a thing to worry for me but for ©Microsoft. And obviously, I should be able to access the data back whenever I need it.

If I would have to implement it on Windows Servers, then I know that I would use a windows service to do this. But I don't know how it can be done for Windows Azure Platform if at all it is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Rinat stated, you can use Lokad's solution. If you choose to do it yourself, you can run a timed task in your worker role - maybe spawn a thread that sleeps, waking every 30 minutes to perform its task. It can then reach out to the Web Services in question (or maybe one thread per Web Service?) and fetch data. You can store it temporarily in Azure Table Storage, which is a fraction of the cost of SQL Azure (0.15 per GB), and then easily read it out of Table Storage on-demand and transfer to SQL Azure.

Assuming you host your services, storage and SQL Azure are in the same data center (by setting the affinity appropriately), you'd only pay for bandwidth when pulling data from the web service. There'd be no bandwidth charges to retrieve from Table Storage or insert into SQL Azure.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows Azure that's usually Worker Role used to host the cloud processing. In order to accomplish your tasks you'll either need to implement this messaging/scheduling infrastructure yourself or use something like [Lokad.Cloud](http://code.google.com/p/lokad-cloud/) or [Lokad.CQRS](http://code.google.com/p/lokad-cqrs/) open source projects for Azure.

We use Lokad.Cloud for distributed BI processing of hundreds of thousands of series and Lokad.CQRS allows to reliably retrieve and synchronize millions of products on schedule.

There are samples, docs and community in both projects to get you started.